# call nodejs script on ubuntu server remotely from andriod app

Tags: android, node.js, remote-access

I have an app that trying to call some nodejs script on remote server, question is, i need the process to be stable and fast, also i need to retrieve the response string from the script return. Is there any better option for me instead of a framework like loopback?

Comment: You can always create a http server using nodejs using core `http` module or `expressjs` depending on your requirement and then send request to that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a REST server in Node.js using Express: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express.

Creating a trivial call in Express is very easy, e.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/test", function(req, res, next){
    res.status(200).send('Hello World');
});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Express listening on ${port}..`);
```

Calling this via curl

```
curl http://localhost:3000/test
```

You can easily call this REST service from any client, including Android, it will need hosting on some cloud based service, e.g. Heroku, AWS

Comment: how could i get the returned string from nodejs though?

Comment: The Node.js REST server can return a string or a JSON encoded object, XML or whatever encoding you want. Within your Android app you can deserialize the response to whatever object model your wish to use.